# convert dxf to kml with ogr2ogr

Tags: kml

geospatial newbie, I want to convert dxf from autocad to kml, it works but the coordinates don't come out right when I compare them to a kml produced with global_mapper and consequently shifted in the right place when uploading the kmz. Maybe someone can illustrate me how to set the parms right, please.

```
ogr2ogr -f KML -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=-36.7193107889714,-4.418216852011938,0,0,0 +units=m +datum=WGS84 +no_defs " -t_srs epsg:25830 -dialect SQLite -sql "select * from entities where layer='SUPERFICIES  ZV'" SUPERFICIES_ZV.kml D02-32.dxf;
```

Southern Spain ETRS89 30 EPSG:25830

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ogr2ogr -f KML -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs " -t_srs epsg:4326 -dialect SQLite -sql "select * from entities where layer='SUPERFICIES  JI'" SUPERFICIES_JI.kml D02-32.dxf